# Calling up rand-int into a variable

Tags: random, clojure

I need to create random numbers and store them into a variable for multiple calculations and for different calls.

```
(defn position
   (def x (rand-int 2147483647))
   (def y (rand-int 2147483647))
   (def z (rand-int 2147483647))
   )
```

What I want to do is calling this function in a loop, do calculations with it and store this away.

Anyone could help, please? There is probably a better way.

Comment: don't use def's inside def(n)s, the thing you want is better done with `repeatedly`: `(def rands (repeatedly 3 #(rand-int 2147483647)))`, then somewhere else `(let [[x y z] rands] ...do something)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer @leetwinski. From what I have understood, `let` can be used only locally, but what if I have other functions, who need to access the exact same values?

Comment: since you've bound the data to global `rands` var (see `(def rands ...`), this form of let could be used anywhere in your program

Comment: ok, so `let` is local to the program not locally to the `def`- or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @Slarti42 Symbols bound in `let` are only in scope until the `let` exits, and then the `let` evaluates to whatever was its body. If you want the data to be used elsewhere, return the three numbers from the function, as a vector or something, then use the data at the call-site. Creating globals by calling a function is messy.

Comment: Try something like [this](https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/7d246a2c43d88cd9761409e009f9dcbe).

Comment: @Carcigenicate - thanks so much for your reply. I am going to check all the responses.

Answer (score 3):

If you want an arbitrary number of things, you need to use an arbitrarily sized data structure. In this case you can probably use the function [repeatedly](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/repeatedly):

```
(repeatedly 5 #(rand-int 2147483647))
```

In this example we take 5 elements (you can change to as many as you need) from *repeatedly* running the anonymous no-arguments function `#(rand-int 2147483647)` which is what you seem to need.

To generate an infinite lazy sequence of random ints you can use:

```
(repeatedly #(rand-int 2147483647))
```

To generate many positions you can also use repeatedly:

```
(defn rand-position []
    {:x (rand-int 2147483647)
     :y (rand-int 2147483647)
     :z (rand-int 2147483647)})

(def positions (repeatedly rand-position))

(take 5 positions) ;; will generate 5 random positions, each represented as a map
```

Comment: Yes, but where are the values then stored, please? I need to do some calculations with it.

Comment: @Slarti42 I've elaborated my answer to fit more into the context of your question.

Comment: thanks for this. I will go evaluate everything in this thread (as well getting my head around this ;) )

Answer (score 0):

With functional programming, I won't suggest you go down the path of defining  global variables (using `def`).  It is better to design your functions to operate on some data structure and returns the same or yet other data structure.  In your case, the data-structure is called `position`.  Given it is not a primitive (like integer), you have to decide how to model it.  With Clojure, you can either pick a vector or a map for it then all your functions have to follow.  Here is how I would go through this development process:

**Warning:** long reply ahead...

*Prologue*

```clj
(require '[clojure.spec.alpha :as s])
(require '[clojure.spec.gen.alpha :as gen])

(def gen-samples
  "A function to create a generator, and to generate 
   some samples from it in one step"
  (comp gen/sample s/gen))
```

*Spec out your data structure*

```clj
;; dimension is an integer between 0 to 2147483647
(s/def ::dim (s/int-in 0 2147483647))

(gen-samples ::dim)
;; => (1 0 2 1 0 0 2 0 0 27)

;; Option 1: position as a collection of 3 dimensions
(s/def ::position (s/coll-of ::dim :count 3))

(gen-samples ::position)
;; => ([0 0 0] [0 0 0] [1 0 0] [0 1 1] [1 0 1] [3 2 1] [26 1 0] [7 1 1] [6 24 1] [2 0 21])

;; Option 2: position as a map - with x,y,z as keys and with dimension as values
(s/def ::x ::dim)
(s/def ::y ::dim)
(s/def ::z ::dim)
(s/def ::position (s/keys :req-un [::x ::y ::z]))

(gen-samples ::position)
;; => ({:x 1, :y 1, :z 0} {:x 0, :y 0, :z 0} {:x 1, :y 2, :z 1} {:x 1, :y 2, :z 0} {:x 2, :y 2, :z 5} {:x 4, :y 1, :z 13} {:x 4, :y 8, :z 7} {:x 2, :y 5, :z 10} {:x 22, :y 3, :z 4} {:x 124, :y 1, :z 8})
```

*Assuming you take option 2, now spec out your function*

```clj
;; in this case, move-east is a function which takes a position
;; and returns another position - with x-dimension of the 
;; new position always greater than the old one
(s/fdef move-east
  :args (s/cat :pos ::position)
  :ret ::position
  :fn #(> (-> % :ret :x) (-> % :args :pos :x)))
```

*Implementation - the easy part*

```clj
(defn move-east [pos]
  (update pos :x inc))
```

*Some manual test*

```clj
(-> ::position gen-samples first)
;; => {:x 1, :y 1, :z 0}

(move-east *1)
;; => {:x 2, :y 1, :z 0}
```

*Auto test based on the spec*

```clj
(require '[clojure.spec.test.alpha :as stest])

(-> `move-east
    stest/check
    stest/summarize-results)
;; => {:total 1, :check-passed 1}

;; what if my function is wrong?
(defn move-east [pos]
  (update pos :x dec))

(-> `move-east
    stest/check
    stest/summarize-results)
;; => {:total 1, :check-failed 1}

;; what is wrong?
(-> `move-east
    stest/check
    first
    stest/abbrev-result)

;; which basically returns a result like below...
;; showing return x is -1 and hence fails the ::dim spec
{:clojure.spec.alpha/problems
 ({:path [:ret :x],
   :pred
   (clojure.core/fn
     [%]
     (clojure.spec.alpha/int-in-range? 0 2147483647 %)),
   :val -1,
   :via [:play/dim],
   :in [:x]}),
 :clojure.spec.alpha/failure :check-failed}
```

Comment: thanks for your elaborate explanation. I will go over this and learn. I will let you know once I "got it".